# New electrical engineer seeking advice on electrical design for hotel!

Tags: design, electrical

I am a recent graduate who is working on a brand new hotel project. I am helping to design the electrical system. I was wondering if anyone who is in the field would be willing to help me by giving me step by step advice on the entire process of designing an electrical system for a commercial building (A hotel in particular)? Any advice and guidance will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Like your other question, this one is not a good fit for the site.  It's much too broad of a question.

Comment: Did you check out Richard Hammond's documentary? Richard Hammond Engineering Connections S03E01 Burj Al Arab

Comment: I am watching it now...